# Can the PostgreSQL C API (libpq) allow you to use the result rather than store it?

Tags: c++, sql, postgresql, network-programming

When performing a query that returns data, the MySQL C API allows you to specify whether you want to "use" or "store" the result set. To "use" the result set means the results are only sent from the server to the client when requested (e.g., one row is sent to the client each time that row is accessed). To "store" the result set means the entire result set is sent from the server to the client "in advance". The former requires less memory on the client, the latter more memory.

Does the PostgreSQL C API provide similar functionality?

Comment: Note that [cursors](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-declare.html) at the SQL level are the primary method for a postgres client app to achieve piecemeal retrieval.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to this question can be found here:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-single-row-mode.html

> ... call PQsetSingleRowMode immediately after a successful call of PQsendQuery (or a sibling function).

Note that this is only available in PostgreSQL 9.2 or greater.